# How to render WITH the default checkerboard as background?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, image

Ok there are a ton of questions on getting a transparent background and NOT having background be checkerboard in final render, but what if you WANT this checkerboard pattern as your final background?

[image]

Ive tried unchecking my Transparent box - I'm in cycles.

Comment: You need to create a background that has such texture.

Comment: How do I get that as png? Isn't it stored somewhere?

Comment: you would need to create one. Use a checkerboard texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create it like any other texture you would want to use in the background.

Here I did it for you. I made it tilable too.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > image as planes.

Then put it as your Background (Probably shadless is best option for this).

***EDIT:***  OP wanted it animated.

Ok I will solve it 90% of the way for you.

You will need at least a 4K Texture for this (So I created it for you, 1 small problem, we will get to that shortly).

Here is a link to 4K texture (MODS not sure where I should put this.)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1D_FiZ92xwt7m-gWxbS6p2S7x4XrNobpA

Set it as your environment background.

*If you are using an HDRI you will need to set up the nodes like below so you can see the image of the BG you want but have the lights and reflection of your origianl HDRI.

***The problem*** with the 4K texture is that it needs to be "Spherized" (I think I just made that word up). I didnt look how to do this in Photoshop that is why you see the squares stretched a little in the GIF I provided. I also provided what an HDRI should look like so it is wrapped around the world correctly. I know how to do this in Blender (Panaramic, Equirectangluar) but havent looked how to do it in Photoshop.

If you look at the gif you can see the checker BG change from the OG to the one I made, Its real quick.

Keep in mind the texture will be turning with your camera, not like how it stays static in the viewport. This can be distracting.

[image]
[image]

This is not a real HDRI this is just what they look like [HDRI HAVEN](https://hdrihaven.com/)
[image]

[image]

Or you could just make a huge sphere to cover everything in your scene (might cut off some of your sun lamps) apply the texture to the sphere and make sure you have your lights and camera in the sphere.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm panning around in my scene - a single image plane won't work. How do I tile the background image because setting world background to image as this Just makes it all gray

Comment: Edited answer!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using a Checker Texture for the Background material using Window coordinates. It's not perfect but I think gives a pretty good impression.

[image: faked transparent background]

You'll need to adjust the Mapping node to match the camera aspect ratio.

This essentially just textures the environment using a Checker texture mapped based on Window coordinates, and only for Camera rays.

Comment: would this move with the camera/look static?

Comment: @skyguy Since it uses Window coordinates, moving the camera won’t affect the position or orientation of the squares in the frame - it will behave the same as for the real ‘transparent’ checker effect with the squares moving with the camera.